# selectSingleNode failing with Soap Response VB6

Tags: soap, vb6

I have used this same code for many other projects and had no issues but for some reason it will not work here. Every time I get to the "If Not .selectSingleNode(strNode) Is Nothing Then" it comes back with nothing and drops me to the else. I have been able to verify the XML that is returned it is listed below as well as the code block that is reading it.

Unfortunately I have to develop this in VB6 in order to maintain compatibility with another product.

The Code is as follows:

```
With objXMLResponse
    Dim strNode As String
    strNode = "//PingResponse/PingResult/ResultCode"
    If Not .selectSingleNode(strNode) Is Nothing Then
        If .selectSingleNode(strNode).Text = "Success" Then
            MsgBox "We have succeded", vbOKOnly
        Else
            MsgBox "We have failed", vbOKOnly
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "We have failed", vbOKOnly
    End If
End With
```

The Soap Response is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <PingResponse xmlns="http://avatax.avalara.com/services">
         <PingResult>
            <TransactionId>784293066</TransactionId>
            <ResultCode>Success</ResultCode>
            <Version>14.5.0.53</Version>
         </PingResult>
      </PingResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have code below and its working fine (I am hitting "We have succeeded" message) with the data sample you provided

Are you forgetting to load XML file?
Your code does not specify how you load XML data. If loading from a file, do you have access to it?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim objXMLResponse As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim success As Boolean

    success = objXMLResponse.Load("C:\Temp\123.txt")
    If success Then
        With objXMLResponse
            Dim strNode As String
            strNode = "//PingResponse/PingResult/ResultCode"
            If Not .selectSingleNode(strNode) Is Nothing Then
                If .selectSingleNode(strNode).Text = "Success" Then
                    MsgBox "We have succeded", vbOKOnly
                Else
                    MsgBox "We have failed", vbOKOnly
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "We have failed", vbOKOnly
            End If
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Error loading XML file"
    End If
End Sub
```